# Saving Mac address in variable in a bash Script and using it to check for changes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to create a bash script.

1. The script asks the user for an IP address
2. The script then greps the `arp -a` command for the line that the IP address is on.
3. The MAC address is saved as a variable called MAC.
4. The script checks that the MAC address has not changed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Xdetect

echo "Welcome to Xdetect"
echo "Enter IP address of device to monitor (usually default gateway)"
read IP  

MAC=arp -a | grep $IP | awk {'print $4'}
echo =$MAC
while : 'arp -a | grep $IP | awk {'print $4'}' = $MAC

do
echo "Mac has not changed"
 sleep 2
done
```

The script does not work, it loops and echoes `MAC has not changed` even when the mac address changes.

Just before it loops an error appears saying: `Xdetect.sh 9: Xdetect.sh: -a: not found`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should a) read a good tutorial, for example the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and/or [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) and b) use http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it tells you. First glance: assigning output of commands to variables, parameter quoting, quoting for awk commands, `while` loop syntax...

Comment: `MAC=$(arp -a | grep $IP | awk '{print $4}')` also `echo $MAC` and `while [ "$(arp -a | grep $IP | awk '{print $4}')" = "$MAC" ]`

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `test` instead of the null command `:` in your `while` statement? Something like this, without the anti-pattern grep|awk:

```
MAC=$(arp -a | awk -v ip="$IP" '$2 == "("ip")" { print $4 }')
echo "$MAC"
while test $(arp -a | awk -v ip="$IP" '$2 == "("ip")" { print $4 }') = "$MAC"; do
   echo "Mac has not changed"
   sleep 2
done
```

Your observation that the message "Mac has not changed" is printed repeatedly is because `:` is a null-command always returning true and ignoring (only expanding) its arguments. Effectively your code does

```
while true; do
   echo echo "Mac has not changed"
   sleep 2
done
```

Comment: A little bit sloppy -- since the IP is being treated as a regex there and `.` is a wildcard, `1.2.1.4` would be matched by `132.143`, no matter what other digits are present.